# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded MATLAB

Tags: java, matlab, pdf, graph, eps

I've read all the answers associated to question "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded". I got a practical instance where this message appears in Matlab. These are some of the lines in the MATLAB code:

```
    figure(2)
    surfl(fkernel); xlabel('f_t (x)'); ylabel('Months, Jul.14- Jan.16'); 
    title('12m Inflation, EEM-Peru');
    colormap(pink);    % change color map
    shading interp;    % interpolate colors across lines and faces
    view(153,52);
    eval(['print -depsc -r300 ',g,'7a']);
    eval(['print -depsc -r200 ',g,'7b']);
    eval(['print -depsc -r100 ',g,'7c']);
    eval(['print -depsc ',g,'7d']);
    eval(['print -depsc2 -r300 ',g,'7e']);
    eval(['print -depsc2 -r200 ',g,'7f']);
    eval(['print -depsc2 -r100 ',g,'7g']);
    eval(['print -depsc2 ',g,'7h']);
    eval(['print -dpdf ',g,'7i']); 
    close;
```

I wanted this detailed 3D graph to be saved into many alternative formats. The files were succesfully saved BUT I suppose the problems associated with Java occurred just on the last eval-print (variable g is just a common string for the file names). This command should have saved the 3D graph into a PDF file.

I checked all files created with the above lines with GSview & Acrobat Reader (for the last one). Only Acrobat Reader had trouble while uploading the PDF file, sending the following message "Error while opening the file: it is damaged and cannot be repaired".

Last information for you Guys: other EPS files saved associated with 2D graphs were small files (between 20-300KB), BUT all the 3D-graph EPS files sucessfully created with the above lines produced huge EPS files: between 261000-276000KB !

Comment: You need to increase heap allocation for your matlab proces.s

Comment: Is your goal to somehow get such large files done or are you looking for better ways to export the data? I assume `shading flat` will reduce the data size.

Comment: There is no reason to use `eval` here, [avoid it when possible](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/string-evaluation.html). In this case `print` is simply a function you can call: `print('-depsc','-r300 ',g,'7a');`